# Does a lightning component with conditional properties reevaluate when attributes changed?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have a series of components that render differently based on certain of their properties :

```
<aura:component controller="ChessGameDataServiceClass">

<aura:attribute name="pieceType" type="String" default="utility:setup"/>
<aura:attribute name="color" type="String" default="none" />

<aura:if isTrue="{!v.color == 'none'}">
    <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="{!v.pieceType}" alternativeText="nah"
                      class="BigButton BigIcon SalesforceStandardEmpty SalesforceStandardButton"
                      onclick="{! c.highlightPossibleMoves }"/>

    <aura:set attribute="else">
        <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="{!v.pieceType}" alternativeText="nah"
                      class="{! v.color == 'white' ? 'BigButton BigIcon SalesforceStandardWhite SalesforceStandardButton' : 'BigButton BigIcon SalesforceStandardBlack SalesforceStandardButton'}"
                      onclick="{! c.highlightPossibleMoves }"/>
    </aura:set>
</aura:if>


</aura:component>
```

I have controller that is changing attributes on some of these:

```
var icon = pieceToMove.get("v.pieceType");
    var color = pieceToMove.get("v.color");
    var pieceName = pieceToMove.get("v.name");
    //if(moveToPiece.get("v.pieceType") != 'utility:survey){ Alex--add to list attribute capturedBlack or capturedWhite}

    moveToPiece.set("v.pieceType",icon);
    moveToPiece.set("v.color", color);
    moveToPiece.set("v.name",pieceName);

    //set the square recently vacated to empty
    pieceToMove.set("v.pieceType","utility:minimize_window");
    pieceToMove.set("v.color", "none");
    pieceToMove.set("v.name", "empty");

    //change the new squares theme appropriately
    //-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
    $A.util.removeClass(moveToPiece,"SalesforceStandardButton SalesforceStandardEmpty")
    $A.util.removeClass(pieceToMove,"SalesforceStandardButton SalesforceStandardEmpty");
```

It seems that the 'piece' component changes colors back to the default after these attributes are changed. Will a lightning component re evaluate its conditionals when a few attributes are changed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, when a render cycle happens, everything gets set back to the way the view state expects it to be. You should set the styles as attributes so that they will be correctly rendered during rendering cycles, *or* you should use afterRender to touch up the elements that need to be (re)modified. In general, you should avoid mixing custom rendering and default rendering when possible.